# How many kg we need to take a mixture of $50$ kg and value of $720$ euro?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

how many kilos of coffee value of $900$ euro per kg , and how many of the $600$ euro must mix , to obtain a mixture of $50$ kg and value of $720$ euro per 720 per kg?

Could anyone give any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the following system of two equations in two variables:

- $x+y=50$
- $(900x+600y)/50=720$